# Pow() function giving error regarding data types

Tags: dart

```
import 'dart:math';

void main (){
    int num = 235;
    var numToString = num.toString();
    var result = numToString.split('').map(int.parse).reduce((t,e)=>pow(t,t)+pow(e,e));
    print(result);
}
```

I am trying to solve a problem that wants me to check if the number is an Armstrong Number or not. I have tried to read the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/be/137378/dart-math/pow.html) but was unable to really work out the issue.

```
Error: A value of type 'num' can't be returned from a function with return type 'int'.
    var result = numToString.split('').map(int.parse).reduce((t,e)=>pow(t,t)+pow(e,e));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by [the `pow` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-math/pow.html), `pow` is declared to return a `num`, so that's the *static* type known to the compiler.  Depending on its arguments, that `num` could actually be an `int` or a `double` at runtime (which the compiler will not know about):

> If `x` is an `int` and `exponent` is a non-negative `int`, the result is an `int`, otherwise both arguments are converted to doubles first, and the result is a `double`.

Meanwhile, your call to `reduce` operates on a `List<int>` and therefore expects `int` arguments.

If you can logically guarantee that the first argument is an `int` and that the second argument is non-negative (which you can in this case), you can safely cast the result of `pow` to an `int`:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  int num = 235;
  var numToString = num.toString();
  var result = numToString
      .split('')
      .map(int.parse)
      .reduce((t, e) => (pow(t, t) + pow(e, e)) as int);
  print(result);
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to store arbitrary numbers and not just integers, you can use `List<num>` instead of `List<int>` by giving an explicit type argument to `.map` instead of letting it be inferred from `int.parse`:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  int number = 235;
  var numToString = number.toString();
  var result = numToString
      .split('')
      .map<num>(int.parse)
      .reduce((t, e) => pow(t, t) + pow(e, e));
  print(result);
}
```

Note that the above also requires renaming your local `num` variable to avoid colliding with the `num` *type*.

(By the way, the documentation you linked to is rather old (it's from the Dart 1 SDK!).  You should always refer to [the latest SDK documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-math/pow.html) (or to documentation for the SDK version you have).)